# Другой текст по той же ссылке

Tags: html, css

Есть боковое меню. При выборе разных пунктов в соседнем блоке будет соответствующий пункту текст. Остальной контент на странице меняться не будет. Мне обязательной для каждого пункта меню делать новый html файл, или есть какая-то фича и всё можно сделать в одном файле?

Comment: Когда будете формировать html страницу на сервере используя какой нибудь "template engine", тогда можно будет сделать боковое меню в одном файле и просто его "вставлять" в нужный файл.

Comment: возьмите barba.js и проблемы кончатся